# Is there a way to use Siri with my Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, siri, iphone

I have a new Bluetooth headset and would like to use Siri with it. As far as I know, the standard way is to hold down the "call" button for a long press. Unfortunately, my headset treats a 3-second press as a "turn off" signal. Is there a workaround? Possible options I've thought of include shortening the press needed to trigger Siri, remapping the "redial" function (which on this headset involves double-tapping the button", using an alternate combo to trigger Siri, or turning on "Hey Siri" for Bluetooth only.

Comment: Doesn't it have a 2nd button at all? My non-Apple headset [old pre-siri Jawbone] uses the call button long press like yours, as an on/off switch, but has a second button at the back which activates Siri. I'd check the manual.

Comment: i just got my HSP-B4 Bluetooth Headset【Upgraded Bluetooth V5.0】 with 15 Hours Talking Time,WOLFANG Lightweight Noisy Suppression Bluetooth Earpiece for Phone/Laptop/Car Blue from amazon yesterday and i can't find how to activate siri either

Answer (score 1):

Most wireless headsets use a double tap of the main button for voice commands (like Siri)

You are trying to use it like wired headphones that have the controller by trying with the hold of the main button

If it has a second button also try double pressing or holding it

Answer (score 1):

Airpods do this quite well. If you’re using non-apple earbuds - you can either use the hardware control on the phone to activate Siri, connect a Bluetooth keyboard that allows Siri activation or get one that has a hardware control or sensor that operates like AirPods do with a tap to invoke Siri.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another avenue for you to pursue for an answer is to look up yout BT headset on Amazon and check out the Answered Questions, which are located just under Customer Reviews.  That's where I learned that the Skull Candy BT headphones I purchased do not "support" Siri.

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Mommy Me stated, I found out that if I press and hold the call button, quickly say "Hey Siri", then quickly release the call button, you will hear the 3-note headset response and then the Siri "gong" will respond.  If you hold the call button press too long (past the headset 3 note response) it will turn off the headset.  Also make sure you don't release the call button before you completely say "Hey Siri" or nothing will happen.

Answer (score -3):

Press the call button and say “hey siri”